# IPerf - Reverse test

Tags: tcp, bandwidth, iperf

I'm trying to perform a test using IPerf but in a special case. Usually iperf client send data to iperf server, what I need in this case is the server send data back to the client in the same connection.

I don't want a bidirectional test, as it does open a new tcp connection back to the client, and that isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Carlos - please leave alone the edits I made. It's a well-accepted practice here to just ask your question and be done with it. No need to say thank you or to sign your name, as those are automatically taken care of by the sig block below your answer and by you accepting and/or upvoting good answers.

Comment: Are trying to find a utility that opens just one tcp connection for both an up and down transfer test?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking the same question as at:

[iperf-like bidirectional bandwidth measurement through NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/352724/iperf-like-bidirectional-bandwidth-measurement-through-nat)

I responded there, but the tl;dr is that I found a patch for `iperf` that enables NAT'd clients to initiate reverse TCP iperf tests. The full, patched `iperf` code is here:

https://github.com/tierney/iperf